# How to find nearest exclusive polygon with Shapely 2.0

Tags: python, shapely

If I have a dictionary with multiple Polygons like so:

```
poly_dict = {'1': <Polygon1>, '2': <Polygon2>}
```

How can I find the nearest polygon to one of the polygons in the dictionary using Shapely 2.0?

```
# Creating the STRtree
poly_rtree = STRtree(list(poly_dict.values())) # The 2.0 way of making an STRtree
# This works with older versions of Shapely
# rtree.nearest_item(poly_dict[bldg_id], exclusive=True)
# Shapely 2.0 uses `nearest`
nearest_poly = rtree.nearest(poly_dict[bldg_id])
```

But with Shapely 2.0, `exclusive` is not a parameter of `nearest`, so it just returns the (EDIT: index of the) same geometry I send it. How can I make it return `'2'` when `bldg_id = '1'` and `'1'` when `bldg_id = '2'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [query_nearest](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/strtree.html#shapely.STRtree.query_nearest) instead like this which does accept the 'exclusive' parameter:

```py
from shapely import Point, STRtree

n = 3
poly_dict = {str(x): Point((x**2, 0)).buffer(0.3) for x in range(n)}

poly_rtree = STRtree(list(poly_dict.values())) # The 2.0 way of making an STRtree

nearest_poly = [poly_rtree.query_nearest(poly_dict[str(bldg_id)], exclusive=True) for bldg_id in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    print(nearest_poly[i])
```

yielding:

```
[1]
[0]
[1]
```

note the 'all_matches' parameter as well, which if False garantees a single return geometry:

```py
from shapely import Point, STRtree

n = 3
poly_dict = {str(x): Point((x**2, 0)).buffer(0.3) for x in range(n)}

poly_rtree = STRtree(list(poly_dict.values())) # The 2.0 way of making an STRtree

nearest_poly = [poly_rtree.query_nearest(poly_dict[str(bldg_id)], exclusive=True, all_matches=False) for bldg_id in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    print(nearest_poly[i][0])
```